# Data binding in AngularJS using views built on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, validation, laravel-4

**The context:**

I am building a wizard in AngluarJS with tabbed content, where each tab is a step in the wizard. The steps are retrieved from the db via a laravel controller, and the wizard built using ng-repeat. Each tab consists of a blade view which is rendered by the laravel controller and then included in the form using ng-bind-html.

Simplified html:

```
<div class="tab-content">
   <div ng-repeat="task in task_list" class="tab-pane" id="tab{{task.step}}">
       <div ng-bind-html="task.rendered_view"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The problem:**

At each step of the wizard I need to validate the form contents - ideally by Angular POSTing to the laravel controller and then displaying returned errors. However, as the inputs are in the rendered_view I can't retrieve them using ng-model to bind them in AngularJS.

I'm fairly new to Angular so might be missing something obvious but I can't find a solution to this. Any suggestions on a different method of including the views? Or a different method of validation? The final submit at the end of the wizard works fine as the form submit button posts input from all the tabs to the controller, but I would like to include validation in the intermediate steps.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the problem, but perhaps it can be solved by using `ng-init` in the rendered views.

So if the rendered view looks something like this:

```
<div ng-init='validateReponses()'>
    <span>Your inputs and other content here</span>
</div>
```

Then the function validateResponses would be run every time that div is inserted into the DOM.

Edit: It occured to me after posting that I am not sure whether ng-bind-html creates a new scope.  From the docs, I don't think that it does, but if it did, then you might call `$parent.validateResponses()` instead.

Comment: Nope, the function doesn't get called...if it did I'm sure I would be able to see the ng-model bindings as well. No angular is recognised in the rendered view. Its not a scope thing because I also tried giving the view its own controller.